# Apache tomcat 7 runs well on localhost but deployed war files throw exceptions when try to run

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, servlets, tomcat7

I have a jax rs web services in eclipse, they run well on our test server but throw an exception on my local machine when i try to run them in eclipse.

Below is the error it throws

> Message Servlet.init() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   ServletAdaptor threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit not present
>     sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown
>   Source)   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown
>   Source)   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown
>   Source)
>     sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.getMetaArguments(InjectableProviderFactory.java:135)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.add(InjectableProviderFactory.java:93)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory$1.onAdd(InjectableProviderFactory.java:109)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory$1.onAdd(InjectableProviderFactory.java:107)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:204)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.configure(InjectableProviderFactory.java:106)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1153)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Root Cause

Below is the eclipse project web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>leaveMgt</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>webServices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: jdk1.8.0_181  i use jre1.8.0_171 i use eclipse java ee ide photon

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the cause is a missing library in your classpath. Specifically, you have some classes annotated with `@javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit`, but this class is missing from the classpath. So I suggest you list all the libraries deployed in the test webserver (including the /lib libraries) and compare them with the ones deployed in your local server, paying special attention to some of these:

- persistence.jar
- javaee-api-*.jar
- annotations-api-*.jar

.. which are the standard libraries in which `javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit` class might be present.